# ASP.NET - How to add hyperlinks to pie chart sections?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pie-chart

I have a pie chart that uses data returned from a business rules method. Is it possible to allow users to click on the segments of the pie chart by adding hyperlinks to each segment?

I know how to do this in the aspx of the pie chart, but the datasource and series of the data is based on the data returned from the method. Would you use something like: `foreach series with a switch statement for the hyperlink`?

How can I assign a hyperlink to the pie chart segments?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like the sort of thing I was looking for. How would I do this referencing a specific pie chart segment by name? For example, what code would I use to assign a hyperlink to a segment with a specific name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out how to do this using a switch statement to assign a url and query string to specific segment names:

```
Point.Url = "/url?querystring"
```

Answer (score 0):

**to redirect from specific section of pie chart:**

Chart1.Series[0].Points[0].Url="/url1";

Chart1.Series[0].Points[1].Url="/url2";

Chart1.Series[0].Points[2].Url="/url3";

**to redirect from specific legends of pie chart:**

Chart1.Series[0].Points[0].LegendUrl="/url1";

Chart1.Series[0].Points[1].LegendUrl="/url2";

Chart1.Series[0].Points[2].LegendUrl="/url3";

**you can write:**

Chart1.Series[0].Points[0].Url = Chart1.Series[0].Points[0].LegendUrl = "rptPendingBreakdown.aspx";

Answer (score 0):

To redirect from the specific section of the pie chart.

Use:

```
Chart1.Series(0).Points(0).Url="/url1"

Chart1.Series(0).Points(1).Url="/url2"

Chart1.Series(0).Points(2).Url="/url3"
```

[image: pie_chart]

Comment: When posting code, please put 4 spaces in front of the code so that it's easily readable as a code block

Answer (score 0):

[Try this one, it works fine for me](https://forums.asp.net/t/2017375.aspx?Hyperlink%20on%20Bar%20Chart%20in%20asp%20net%20c%20)

```
protected void QuestionResponseChart_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int points = QuestionResponseChart.Series[0].Points.Count;
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i <= points - 1; i++)
            {
                string txt = QuestionResponseChart.Series[0].Points[i].AxisLabel;
                QuestionResponseChart.Series[0].Points[i].Url = "SurveyList.ASPX?txt=" + txt;
            }
        }
```